# hiding nth child tr

Tags: html, css

Apologize for the length of the code. I'm trying to hide the three cells that contain the `$` I can't change the html but I can change the CSS. I've tried:

```
.extra-details table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(-n+4)
```

but that gets the first 4 rows in the second table as well. So my question is this, is there CSS I can use to hide the cell/rows that have the `$` or suggestions on something to search for? cell values have been removed for brevity.

```
<div class="details_column">
    <div class="column">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       Price
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                        $
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                        $
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                        $
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium ">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="medium">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a single line the CSS to select just the `<td>` containing `$` elements would be:

```
div.column:first-child table tr:nth-child(-n+4):not(:nth-child(1)) td:last-child {
    border:2px dashed red;
}
```

as demonstrated in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gybUZ/1). However, please note that this is only tested in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To select a specific first occurrence of an element, use `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child`. With the given structure, the following selector can be used to achieve your goal:

```
.details_column > *:first-of-type table tr:nth-child(2) td,
.details_column > *:first-of-type table tr:nth-child(3) td,
.details_column > *:first-of-type table tr:nth-child(4) td {
    background:red;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BaUYF/

Explanation of CSS:

- Select any element with class *`details_column`*
- Select the any element which is a first typem and contains a `<table>` child.
- Select the 2nd, 3rd and 4th row. of these tables.
- Select all cells in these rows
- Apply a style

Note: The proposed selectors could be adjusted to match your exact wishes. I haven't used it, but the `:not()` selector could also be useful.

Comment: nice. works great! I had an "ah ha!" moment even :) This does, however select the `td` that has the word Price (edited) in it.

Comment: sorry must give this one @andyb after all for a single line solution and the fixed code