# Hide a specific part on an HTML code via CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide a part of an HTML code that is not itself within a tag.

Visually this code gives : **CHF120.95 - CHF152.95**

Goal : Only display **CHF120.95**

with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197432/hiding-nth-child-tr) I managed to hide the last part in CSS, but not the middle part (-).

```css
p.price span:nth-child(n+2) {display:none;}
```

```html
<p class="price">
  <span class="wcpbc-price wcpbc-price-1357" data-product-id="1357">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>
      120.95
    </span>
    " - "
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>
      152.95
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `" - "` isn't selectable with CSS. Try putting it into an HTML element so that you can select it with CSS.

Comment: @Daan it's woocommerce so he can't do that easily. If you can't use a Woocommerce filter, change the font size of .price to 0 and then increase font-size of .amount to whatever you want it to be. It's hacky af but it'll work.

Comment: Yes it's hard to do that, wouldn't there be a way to hide the 2nd child of the first span tag (which is this "-")?

Comment: No there is no way with CSS. You can use JS to remove the text from the span if needed.

Comment: @UnbrandedManchester : Yeah thanks, I'll do that if I cannot hide it

Comment: It's not exactly a child, as it's not an HTML element. It's just part of the content of `<span class="wcpbc-price wcpbc-price-1357" data-product-id="1357">`.

Comment: As for your [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector, you could just do `:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: yeah thanks for the tip. I actually meant to hide the "-" and the last element by doing that, but as you said it's not considered as an HTML element it didn't work. I guess I'll do that with JS then

Comment: This should be done properly with Wordpress/Woocommerce hooks and such in PHP, not with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `visibility` can be used, please see the code snippet.

```css
p.price span:nth-child(n+2) {display:none;}

p.price {
  visibility: hidden;
}

p.price > span > span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">
  <span class="wcpbc-price wcpbc-price-1357" data-product-id="1357">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>
      120.95
    </span>
    " - "
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>
      152.95
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: that's interesting. This actually only displays **CHF**, so there must a way to display the right thing.

Comment: If you run the code snippets, it actually showing CHF 120.95