# remove zero bytes in a <div> element with CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: snapshot empty div]

Hello
I want to eliminate all this zero bytes ("[]") in my div section with a proper CSS statement.
How is that possible?
Thx in advance for any hints.

Comment: There is no real “proper” CSS solution for this - CSS can only select elements, not text nodes on their own. Perhaps you can adapt the workaround that was discussed for a similar question just yesterday, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62061018/hide-a-specific-part-on-an-html-code-via-css But actually removing this junk from the document / DOM, instead of trying to hide it via CSS, would probably be the _real_ “proper” solution here.

Answer (score 0):

In that particular case you can override children elements like that (it's a workaround):

```
.x-dataview-item {
  visibility: collapse;
}
.x-dataview-item .fa {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

But like CBroe said - it's always better to repair such problems in the document itself.

Comment: Thx. but unfortunately this workaraiund didn't hit the aim, because now I got a whitespace there shown.
This issue also only araises in Chrome Browser. In FF this zero element isn't shown. Fine.
You're right, to remove this crap in the document, but I don't know how.
(where I can post here now a code snippet? Should I answer my own question, or edit the first one?)

Comment: @user1547821 Find where this particular element is in the template and check if variable exists and is not empty before printing it in DOM
PS. As for the snippet question: I think the best way would be to edit your initial post, by adding something like:
EDIT:
new questions and appropriate data or snippets